# Product details page keep loading

Tags: magento2

Product details page is just keep loading and not showing any thing , When I checked console  just this error msg appeared

> GET http://localhost/jb-lashes/protecting-sealers.html 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

why this is not appearing ? any idea ?

**EDIT**  My debug.log file

```
[2017-10-03 18:08:42] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:42] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:42] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["LAYOUT_GENERAL_CACHE_TAG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:42] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["BLOCK_HTML"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:42] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["COLLECTION_DATA"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:42] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["REFLECTION"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:42] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["DB_DDL"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:42] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["EAV"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:42] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["CUSTOMER_NOTIFICATION"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:42] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:42] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["INTEGRATION"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:42] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["INTEGRATION_API_CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:42] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["TRANSLATE"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:42] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["WEBSERVICE"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:45] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["LAYOUT_GENERAL_CACHE_TAG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["BLOCK_HTML"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["COLLECTION_DATA"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["REFLECTION"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["DB_DDL"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["EAV"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["CUSTOMER_NOTIFICATION"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["INTEGRATION"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["INTEGRATION_API_CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["TRANSLATE"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:46] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["WEBSERVICE"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:47] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:49] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["DB_DDL"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:55] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":[],"mode":"all"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:55] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":[],"mode":"all"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:08:55] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:09:34] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:10:19] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:10:21] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:10:21] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:10:21] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["LAYOUT_GENERAL_CACHE_TAG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:10:21] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["BLOCK_HTML"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:10:21] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["COLLECTION_DATA"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:10:21] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["REFLECTION"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:10:21] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["DB_DDL"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:10:21] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["EAV"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:10:21] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["CUSTOMER_NOTIFICATION"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:10:21] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:10:21] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["INTEGRATION"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:10:21] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["INTEGRATION_API_CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:10:21] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["TRANSLATE"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:10:21] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["WEBSERVICE"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
[2017-10-03 18:10:29] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://localhost/jb-lashes/protecting-sealers.html","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
```

Comment: It's an Internal Server Error. Check your log file for Error. Some code is breaking your page. Also, check the functionality or extension which you added recently.

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal How to check error log ?

Comment: log file should be inside "var/log" folder

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal yes I know but where will errors gonna appear bro ? that where is problem

Comment: debug.log or system.log

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal  can you check my debug.log file I edited my question . But not getting what is wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66553/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-learner).

Comment: @Learner If any custom modules related to product details page disable that and try to run `clean and flush` commands and try again.

Comment: @magentotwo how can I check which modules are installed on pdp ?

Comment: @Learner disable all custom modules in your project under `app/code` then re run the `clean and flush` commands and try again the product page.

Comment: @magentotwo I dont know how to disable is there any command to do that ?

Comment: @Learner `php bin/magento module:disable Theme_VendorName`.